# how to pull docker image from ecr into EC2 using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform

I am trying to deploy nodejs app into ec2. I have already pushed the docker image into ECR.

How do I deploy it into ec2 now?

Here is my terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  region  = var.region
  profile = "whatsnxt"
}

resource "tls_private_key" "rsa_4096" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

// create key pair for connecting to EC2 via SSH
resource "aws_key_pair" "key_pair" {
  key_name   = var.key_name
  public_key = tls_private_key.rsa_4096.public_key_openssh
}

resource "local_file" "private_key" {
  content  = tls_private_key.rsa_4096.public_key_pem
  filename = var.key_name

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "chmod 400 ${var.key_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami                    = var.ami
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main.id]
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.key_pair.key_name
  tags = {
    Name = var.instance_name
  }
  user_data = <<-EOF
                    #!/bin/bash
                    sudo apt-get update -y
                    sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
                    sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
                    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
                    sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
                    echo \
                    "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
                    "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
                    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
                    sudo apt-get update -y
                    sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin -y
                  EOF  

  root_block_device {
    volume_size           = 15
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
}

data "aws_ecr_image" "service_image" {
    repository_name = "ecr_whatsnxt_repo"
    image_tag       = "dev-v1"
}

resource "aws_default_vpc" "default" {
  tags = {
    Name = "Default webserver VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
  name        = "Webserver SG"
  description = "Webserver Securitu Group"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.default.id

  # ingress {
  #   protocol  = "-1"
  #   self      = true
  #   from_port = 3000
  #   to_port   = 0
  #   cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  # }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 3000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 3000
    to_port     = 3000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Comment: do it within the user data.  Or use Fargate and save yourself time and money bootstrapping your own hosts

Answer (score 0):

To pull the Image from ECR add it in your user-data:

```
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID="123456789"
ECR_IMAGE="IMAGE-NAME"
REGION="us-east-1"

aws --region $REGION ecr get-authorization-token   
#aws --region $REGION ecr describe-registry
aws --region $REGION ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com
sleep 2
docker pull $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/$ECR_IMAGE
```

Using Fargate would save on $$$ and overhead.